# Как заново задекларировать массив string с другим размером и другими значениями?

Tags: c++, строки

Мне нужен код для времени срабатывания кода. Для этого надо сохранять мне в виде string или char *. Так как хочу добавить возможность менять размер и значения массив, надо массив заново задекларировать и заменить значения.
Немного порылся в интернете, вроде бы нашел это решение:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string times_[8]={
  "08:30",
  "09:15",
  "10:00",
  "10:45",
  "11:30",
  "12:15",
  "13:00",
  "13:45"
};

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) cout << times_[i] << endl;
    times_ = new string [3];
    delete[] times_;
    times_[0]="00:00";
    times_[2]="01:00";
    times_[1]="02:00";
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<8; i++) cout << times_[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:
'std::__cxx11::basic_string*'} to 'std::__cxx11::string [8]' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string [8]'}|.

Решение с векторами к сожалению нельзя использовать.

Есть ли другие решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Компилятор всё верно говорит. Вы не можете изменить размер статического массива, и не можете работать потом с ним как с динамическим (new, delete). Используйте `times_` либо как статический, либо как динамический массив, но не одновременно.

Comment: несмотря на все другое, кода вида `times_ = new string [3];
    delete[] times_;` уже должен вызвать вопросы. А потом ещё к этому обращаются. может озвучите полный список "чего нельзя". а то может и указатели нельзя, и std::list.